# Print One to many between 2 lists

Tags: python

Sorry for the wrong output sequence. The one that i changed now has the correct one.

I have two lists in Python as given below

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = [1,2,3]
```

I want to print the output as

a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have two lists, but you combine three lists. Maybe a typo?

Comment: @AppleCrazy Nope, He's asking for a cross product.

Comment: Thanks @Bhargav Rao. The link solved the problem

Comment: For your desired output: `', '.join(''.join(x + str(y)) for x in a for y in b)`

Comment: Sorry. There is change in the output. I need the output in a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use for loops, as below:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = [1,2,3]

for el_a in a:
    for el_b in b:
        print str(el_a) + str(el_b)
```

will produce :

```
a1,a2,a3, b1,b2,b3, c1,c2,c3
```

[Update] 
For the updated sequence:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = [1,2,3]

for el_b in b:
    for el_a in a:
        print str(el_a) + str(el_b)
```

will produce :

```
a1,b1,c1, a2,b2,c2, a3,b3,c3
```

Comment: I just changed the output sequence. Please help on that output

Comment: Thanks. I works!!!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        print a+b
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just changed the output sequence. Please help on that output